# Expected declaration specifiers

Tags: c, list, linked-list

I am learning linked lists in C.  I am new to using pass by references for manipulating the linked lists.  Now I know I'm doing something really foolish in this program.  This program creates a list and then basically returns the number of instances of a particular value(the data of node).  I get an error like so, "Expected declaration specifier" before every statement of main!.

What's going on wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<malloc.h>
    struct list {
            int number;
            struct list *next;
            };
    typedef struct list node;
    void create(node *);
    int count(node **,int);
    main()
    int key,this_many;
    node *head;
    head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    create(head);
    printf("Which number?\n");
    scanf("%d",&key);
    this_many = count(&head,key);
    printf("%d times\n",this_many);
    return 0;
    }
    void create(node *list) {
            printf("Enter a number -999 to stop\n");
            scanf("%d",&list->number);
            if(list->number == -999) {
                    list->next = NULL;
            }
            else {
                    list->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                    create(list->next);
            }
    }
    int count(node **addr_list,int key) {
            int count = 0;
            while(*addr_list != NULL) {
                    if((*addr_list)->number == key) {
                            count++;
                    }
                    *addr_list = (*addr_list)->next;
            }
            return(count);
    }
```

Comment: I think your braces are not balanced?  Can you please format the code a little better?

Comment: I don't see the `main()` starting bracket `{`

Comment: omg..thanks a very foolish mistake indeed it runs perfectly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1. You are not specifying the return type of `main`.
2. You don't have the `{` to start the scope of `main`.

Change the lines starting with `main` to:

```
int main()
{
  int key,this_many;
  node *head;
  head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
  create(head);
  printf("Which number?\n");
  scanf("%d",&key);
  this_many = count(&head,key);
  printf("%d times\n",this_many);
  return 0;
}
```